# Blank classification output in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, classification, landsat

I tried to classify the Landsat images from 2013 to 2022 using the random forest classifier. I have used the below code which has been modified from the one available [here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/04/google-earth-engine-machine-learning-for-land-cover-classification-with-code/). The original code was for SVM classifier. But after running the code I am getting the output as blank. Though a file is generated in the specified storage.

```
/**

 * Function to mask clouds based on the pixel_qa band of Landsat 8 SR data.
 * @param {ee.Image} image Input Landsat 8 SR image
 * @return {ee.Image} Cloudmasked Landsat 8 image
 **/
function maskL8sr(image) {
  // Bits 3 and 5 are cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
  var cloudShadowBitMask = (1 << 3);
  var cloudsBitMask = (1 << 5);
  // Get the pixel QA band.
  var qa = image.select('QA_PIXEL');
  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
                 .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask);
}
//APPLY SCALING FACTOR
function applyScaleFactors(image) {
  var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
  var thermalBands = image.select('ST_B.*').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);
  return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true)
              .addBands(thermalBands, null, true);
}
// Loading Landsat 8 collection
var bands = ['SR_B2', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B5', 'SR_B6', 'SR_B7'];


var l8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2') //Landsat 8 surface reflectance data
         .map(maskL8sr)
         .map(applyScaleFactors);
var image = l8.filterDate('2022-02-01', '2022-2-28').median();
// Define the visualization parameters for fcc.
var visParams = {
  bands: ['SR_B5', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B3'],
  min:0,
  max:0.3,
   };
Map.addLayer(image.clip(geometryp1), visParams, 'false color composite');
// Set map center
Map.centerObject(geometryp1, 10);
Map.addLayer(geometryp1, {}, 'study area', false, 0.2);


// Labeling training data
var polygons = ee.FeatureCollection([
ee.Feature(bareland, {'class': 0}), // bare land
ee.Feature(agriculture, {'class': 1}), // agriculture
ee.Feature(urban, {'class': 2}), // urban
ee.Feature(forest, {'class': 3}), // forest
ee.Feature(water, {'class': 4}), // water
]);

// creation of the training set
var newfc = bareland.merge(agriculture).merge(urban).merge(forest).merge(water);
print(newfc, 'newfc');

// creation of the training set
var newfc = table ;
print(newfc, 'newfc');

// Extract Digital Numbers of pixels in training polygons
// Features/bands used for prediction.
var bands = ['SR_B2', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B5', 'SR_B6', 'SR_B7'];
var training = image.select(bands).sampleRegions({
// Get the training polygons
collection: newfc,
// Set the properties name
properties: ['Id'],
// Set the spatial resolution of the images
scale: 30
});

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Random forest classification
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Make a Random Forest classifier and train it.
var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(1000).train({
  features: training, 
  classProperty: 'Id', 
  inputProperties: (bands)
});

print(classifier);
// Train the classifier
//var trained = classifier.train(newfc, 'class', bands);
//print(trained);

// Get a confusion matrix representing resubstitution accuracy.
print('RF error matrix: ', classifier.confusionMatrix());
print('RF accuracy: ', classifier.confusionMatrix().accuracy());



// List the years, months, and date
var tahun = [2013, 2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020,2021,2022,2023];

var i;
for (i = 0; i<tahun.length;i++){
var data = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T2_L2') .map(maskL8sr)
         .map(applyScaleFactors);
var composite = data.filterDate( tahun[i] + "-" + 02  + "-" + 01, tahun[i] + "-" + 02 + "-" + 28)
.median();
var clipped = composite.clip(geometryp1);
// Classify the satellite image
var classified = clipped.classify(classifier);
// clip classified
var clipped3 = classified.clip(geometryp1);
}

// Show the composite image 654 and the classification result
Map.addLayer(clipped , {bands: ['SR_B6', 'SR_B5', 'SR_B4'], max: 65000}, "date " + tahun[i] + "-" + 02  + "-" + 28, false );
Map.addLayer(classified,
{min: 1, max: 6, palette: [ 'yellow', 'brown', 'sienna', 'darkgreen', 'red','blue'  ]},
'LC_classification'+ tahun[i] + "-" + 02  + "-" + 28, false);

 Export.image.toDrive({
  image: clipped3,
  folder: 'LULC',
  description: 'LC_classification_summer'+ tahun[0],
  scale: 30,
  region: geometryp1,
  maxPixels: 1e10,
});
 

 
 Export.image.toDrive({
  image: clipped3,
  folder: 'LULC',
  description: 'LC_classification_summer'+ tahun[1],
  scale: 30,
  region: geometryp1,
  maxPixels: 1e10,
});

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: clipped3,
  folder: 'LULC',
  description: 'LC_classification_summer'+ tahun[2],
  scale: 30,
  region: geometryp1,
  maxPixels: 1e10,
});

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: clipped3,
  folder: 'LULC',
  description: 'LC_classification_summer'+ tahun[3],
  scale: 30,
  region: geometryp1,
  maxPixels: 1e10,
});

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: clipped3,
  folder: 'LULC',
  description: 'LC_classification_summer'+ tahun[4],
  scale: 30,
  region: geometryp1,
  maxPixels: 1e10,
});

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: clipped3,
  folder: 'LULC',
  description: 'LC_classification_summer'+ tahun[5],
  scale: 30,
  region: geometryp1,
  maxPixels: 1e10,
});

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: clipped3,
  folder: 'LULC',
  description: 'LC_classification_summer'+ tahun[6],
  scale: 30,
  region: geometryp1,
  maxPixels: 1e10,
});

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: clipped3,
  folder: 'LULC',
  description: 'LC_classification_summer'+ tahun[7],
  scale: 30,
  region: geometryp1,
  maxPixels: 1e10,
});

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: clipped3,
  folder: 'LULC',
  description: 'LC_classification_summer'+ tahun[8],
  scale: 30,
  region: geometryp1,
  maxPixels: 1e10,
});

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: clipped3,
  folder: 'LULC',
  description: 'LC_classification_summer'+ tahun[9],
  scale: 30,
  region: geometryp1,
  maxPixels: 1e10,
});

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: clipped3,
  folder: 'LULC',
  description: 'LC_classification_summer'+ tahun[10],
  scale: 30,
  region: geometryp1,
  maxPixels: 1e10,
});
```

The output is shown below.
[image]

Where am I going wrong?

Note: No error was showing in the console.

Comment: Please share the code link. The training samples are not shared, so it is not possible to test your code.

Comment: I think the problem is with property name in `sampleRegions()` and `smileRandomForest().train()`. Your training samples have the property  'class' as you have defined in newfc. The `properties` and `classProperty` should be 'class', but you have given 'Id'.